# How to calculate Regression Error in python?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, regression

I calculated and found linear regression parameters of two columns of my data frame by doing

```
Answer_trial= numpy.polyfit(table.Column1,table.  Column2, 1)
```

which outputted an m and b of `array([  635.75924642, 18140.1330612 ])`

How do I find regression error of each state of my data (my dataframe has a column of state), where the regression error respresents the distance of each state to the regression line, in the Column2 variable, where a positive error means that the state is greater than the line.
I know I have to use the m,b values somehow but I am confused.